# How to Pickup exact quantity of agents who meet the required criteria in Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I have the following model that I am working on. The model structure is as follows,

[image]

The parameters are predefined using a two functions inside the Order agent as follows,
[image]

*Please note that my population orders is initially empty and I am adding my source agents to custom population orders.*

Now, I have defined another population called products with one parameter ProductType, and it is also initially empty and I am adding the agents at enter1, enter2, and enter3 to the custom population products.

Now, once my orders reach the following delays block (after delay is complete) the following code is called,

*

```
for (int i=0; i<agent.quarts_fill;i++){
Product product=new Product(agent.getIndex());
enter1.take(product);
}
for (int i=0; i<agent.gallon_fill;i++){
Product product=new Product(agent.getIndex());
enter2.take(product);
}
for (int i=0; i<agent.bucket_fill;i++){
Product product=new Product(agent.getIndex());
enter3.take(product);
}
```

- 

[image]

So, what I am doing is that, I am defining the parameter ProductID of agent population products as per the Order agent Index number which I am obtaining using agent.getIndex() function.

**Now, I am moving to the part where I am troubled**

[image]

In the pickup block, I am trying to pickup the exact number of agents (product that meets the criteria with certain ProductID) using the following function

```
(count(queue1, q-> q.ProductID==container.getIndex())== container.OrderSize)?
container.OrderSize : container.OrderSize
```

To some extent I am confident about the above code, but the issue is the false statement. You can notice once the Java Ternary Expression is false, it will pickup almost all agent ( Product) with the required quantity. So, it is not taking into consideration the criteria ProductID.

What should I do to **wait** in case the amount of agents with specific ProductID at queue1 is not yet the amount equals to container.OrderSize???

And recently I noticed container.getIndex() is entirely new, and it is not representing the ((Order)agent).getIndex(). So what should I do to refer to the Order get Index?

Answer (score 0):

using getIndex() for the purpose of giving id to your orders is bad idea. It works fine until the moment when order start leaving population. After first order has left the population getIndex() becomes misleading as it ignores those old orders. Rather than using getIndex() i recomend you to use something like self.out.count(). This code would refer to the "out" port of the current block and will give you a proper incrementation of  your order ids.

Comment: you can also use `getID()` which provides a "stable" unique number

Answer (score 0):

Well I found I was using Java Ternary Expression for no reason at all,

the condition

```
(count(queue1, q-> q.ProductID==container.getIndex())== container.OrderSize)
```

should be sufficient enough for the problem above.